# Get sum of each row added together in while loop

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a mysql table that contains an integer in each row.  What I am trying to do is get the sum of the integers. Here is what I currently have that is working.

```
$cn = 0;
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM members WHERE member='$userid'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
$i = $row['number'];

$cn = $cn + $i;
}

echo $cn;
```

So I make $cn equal zero then each time it goes through the loop it will add the number from the matching row.

Does anyone have a better idea on how to accomplish this?   Thanks!

Comment: check if $row['number']; is returning something.

Comment: Aggregation function `SUM`

Comment: I'm embarrassed.  I looked over the code a hundred times and didn't see a problem.  I had $i = $rw['number'];  should of had $i = $row['number'];   So silly.   Should of c/p instead of re-writing my code, would of spotted it right away before I asked and saved us all the trouble.  Thanks for the help everyone.   That being said, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use PHP or here a loop for that, because your database can do the job for you.

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT sum(number) FROM members WHERE member='$userid'");
```

Comment: Thanks, so then the sum will be in the $sql variable?  Sorry for the dumb question, never used count.

Comment: @ButterDog: You have to fetch the row for sure ... with `mysqli_fetch_row($sql)` or `mysqli_fetch_array($sql)`

Comment: @ButterDog: What you should have learned here is: Use the database in favor of looping (uselessly) through data with php.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the sum of the column number for each member with a particular user id

```
$sum = 0;
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT SUM(number) as number_total FROM members WHERE member='$userid'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
      $sum = $row['number_total'];
}
```

`$sum` will have the total

Comment: Thanks anurupr,  I marked djot as right because they got in first and their solution didn't rquire the loop so a bit less code.  Like your way too, I will keep it in mid for the future when it may be helpful.  Thanks again.

Comment: True. instead of the `while`  you could use `if` and it wouldn't be a loop.